# How to fix mysql 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: thats the error log am getting on my browser]

Have tried reinstalling xampp but it continues to give me the above error!
have tried editing config.inc.php, however because of access right of the file I could not archive that either. Have wasted time on this already!

I need someone to help please

Comment: I dont suppose you have a MySQL sever instance running that was installed before you installed XAMPP

Comment: mysql server is running

Comment: @RiggsFolly, as you can see from the error log, mysql is the one throwing the error

Comment: Yes, BUT if you have 2 instances of MySQL then possibly the one that is started in not the XAMPP one. And that instance may be configured differently, hence the error

Comment: have stopped all other instances, its still throwing the same error! am tired already

Comment: everything happened after I tried changing root password from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the [server is running](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-testing.html).
2. Ensure the password and username are correct [and change it if not](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

If these two steps don't work, leave a comment and I'll investigate further.